# InDesign / Delete entire line if field is empty

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, data-merge

I'm working on automating donations and was wondering if, when using Data Merge, it is possible on export to auto remove a line, if those fields don't have any data in them.

Per example,

[image: Screenshot 1]

After Data Merge,

[image: Screenshot 2]

Goal is to remove the bottom two lines if there isn't a second donation turning it into this,

[image: Screenshot 3]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Include the $ symbol in Excel or whatever program you use
2. Make sure "Remove blank lines for empty fields" is selected in the
   DM options
3. Create two paragraph styles for "amount" and "date". Set them as numbered list. In the bullets and numbering options, type the prefix (e.g. "Donation amount") instead of the numbering marker ^#

[image]

Comment: I understood everything except your third point. Could you be a little more specific? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sam I've edited my answer. Hopefully it will make more sense

Comment: That did it beautifully; merci!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to place a null character in the blank space in the excel document